# need help with a couple of RegEx

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, gridview

I'm creating a site using asp.net and C# and i just need to know some regex to validate/highlight my gridview.

I need to highlight these cells in their own columns:

```
1- APR, MAR, etc. (three letters exactly)
2- 2011, 2012, etc.  (year)
3- blank cell in gridview
```

Some links/tutorials on basic regex would also help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `[A-Z]{3}`
2. `\d{4}`

For 1, you could also use `(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|...)` (you get the idea). Also, if you wanted to match all Unicode letters, you could swap `[A-Z]` with `\pL`.

If you didn't want these matched midstring, add a word boundary (`\b`) on each side.

Comment: @alex what do you mean by midstring? like this? XXJANXX?

Comment: In Denmark we have like æøå and those wouldn't fit A-Z. For a more generic purpose I would suggest using \w instead [A-Z] since you wouldn't be able to catch special language specific characters otherwise.

Comment: @cyberzed `\w` is just shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` isn't it? You'd be better off using Unicode character classes, e.g. `\pL`.

Comment: @alex not according to the small block I just tested in linqpad :)